# python, convert list into similar sublists

Tags: python, list

I wanted to convert list of names into similar sub-lists.  example

```
['yam-nb-109.0-8438773.i686.rpm', 'yam-nb-112.0-10561609.i686.rpm', 
 'yam-ris-105.0-7269382.i686.rpm', 'yam-ris-106.0-7451269.i686.rpm', 
 'yam-ris-107.0-7899661.i686.rpm', 'yam-ris-112.0-10577466.i686.rpm', 
 'yam-logg-110.0-9833588.i686.rpm', 'yam-logg-111.0-10278753.i686.rpm', 
 'yam-logg-99.0-5275910.i686.rpm', 'yamboard-114.0-10902994.i686.rpm', 
 'yamboard-114.0-11436227.i686.rpm']
```

into

```
[['yam-nb-109.0-8438773.i686.rpm', 'yam-nb-112.0-10561609.i686.rpm'], 
 ['yam-ris-105.0-7269382.i686.rpm', 'yam-ris-106.0-7451269.i686.rpm', 'yam-ris-107.0-7899661.i686.rpm', 'yam-ris-112.0-10577466.i686.rpm'], 
 ['yam-logg-110.0-9833588.i686.rpm', 'yam-logg-111.0-10278753.i686.rpm', 'yam-logg-99.0-5275910.i686.rpm'],
 ['yamboard-114.0-10902994.i686.rpm', 'yamboard-114.0-11436227.i686.rpm']]
```

Any suggestions here would be helpful.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: How u are selecting element in sublist ? is there any formula which apply to list to convert list to sublist ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to group the similar packages into lists.

Answer (score 6):

Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> import itertools
>>>
>>> pkgs = [
...     'yam-nb-109.0-8438773.i686.rpm', 'yam-nb-112.0-10561609.i686.rpm',
...     'yam-ris-105.0-7269382.i686.rpm', 'yam-ris-106.0-7451269.i686.rpm',
...     'yam-ris-107.0-7899661.i686.rpm', 'yam-ris-112.0-10577466.i686.rpm',
...     'yam-logg-110.0-9833588.i686.rpm', 'yam-logg-111.0-10278753.i686.rpm',
...     'yam-logg-99.0-5275910.i686.rpm', 'yamboard-114.0-10902994.i686.rpm',
...     'yamboard-114.0-11436227.i686.rpm'
... ]
>>>
>>> pkg_name = lambda fn: fn.rsplit('-', 2)[0]
>>> [list(grp) for _, grp in itertools.groupby(pkgs, key=pkg_name)]
[['yam-nb-109.0-8438773.i686.rpm',
  'yam-nb-112.0-10561609.i686.rpm'],
 ['yam-ris-105.0-7269382.i686.rpm',
  'yam-ris-106.0-7451269.i686.rpm',
  'yam-ris-107.0-7899661.i686.rpm',
  'yam-ris-112.0-10577466.i686.rpm'],
 ['yam-logg-110.0-9833588.i686.rpm',
  'yam-logg-111.0-10278753.i686.rpm',
  'yam-logg-99.0-5275910.i686.rpm'],
 ['yamboard-114.0-10902994.i686.rpm',
  'yamboard-114.0-11436227.i686.rpm']]
```

**NOTE**

Above code is assuming

- you want group file names by their package name
- filenames are sorted
- version number format after package names are identical (`package_name-version-version2.i686.rpm`)

Comment: +1, but let's hope that it's not just a coincidence that the numbers after `yamboard` were identical.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, Thank you for your comment. I added a mention about the version number.

Comment: Well, it's not just the format, is it? And the version numbers themselves are definitely not identical with the other packages. Perhaps it would be better to use a regex like `^\D+` as the sorting criterion - although that would fail if package names contain digits. The problem remains unsolvable until the OP clarifies how to split the package names.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I wanted to split with packagenames and group the similar packages into one list.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, How about regex like `.*?(?=-\d)`? This will fail if version starts with non-digit, though.

Comment: Good idea, but we still need an exact definition from @Sreeks where a package name ends and where the version number starts. Most likely, your suggestion is the best we can do.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: This is the format of the above packages " package_name-version-buildnumber.arch.rpm ". With the above code I'm ending up with TypeError: 'list' object is not callable. Not sure I'm missing some thing here...

Comment: Ah, OK, so `rsplit('-', 2)` can be relied upon after all.

Answer (score -2):

With no libraries:

```
sort(fromlist)
outlist=[["-"]]
for i in fromlist:
  if i[:i.rfind("-")]!=outlist[-1][-1][:outlist[-1][-1].rfind("-")]:
    outlist.append([])
  outlist[-1].append(i)
```

Comment: And that's precisely the reason why you should be using the libraries. Even if that code is correct, it's quite unreadable.

Comment: -1 This a case study about obfuscation, not an answer attempt; right?

Comment: I tried to answer, but editted the head when saw the other option. Some people have just pure Python with no external libraries.

Comment: @Arusekk, itertools is a standard library